# Как передать значения в input из Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой вот скрипт для построения дерева, я задаю в `input` значения, и после нажатия кнопки ajax-ом строится дерево, но при перезагрузки страницы `input` пустые, записал эти значения в `localStorage`, но вот как записать их в `input` после перезагрузки страницы не знаю, помогите пожалуйста.

Скрипт:

```
 $("body").on("click", "#buildTree", function (e) {

 var osdch = $("input[data-field=osdch]").val();
 var kiz = $("input[data-field=kiz]").val();
 localStorage.setItem("osdch", osdch);
 localStorage.setItem("kiz", kiz);

 var url = window.location.pathname;
     $.jstree.destroy();
     $('#jstree').jstree({
        'core': {
        "themes": {"stripes": true},
        'data': {// accepts $.ajax object with its standart properties
                method: "post",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (node) {
                if (node.id !== '#') {
                  osdch = node.li_attr.osdch;
                  kiz = node.li_attr.kiz;
                                                        }
              return {"kiz": kiz, "osdch": osdch};
                                                    },
              success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      return data;
                                                    },
              error: function (node) {

                                                    }
                                                }

                                            },

       "search": {
           "case_sensitive": false,
           "show_only_matches": true
                                            },

      "plugins": ["search", "state", "wholerow"]

                                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[data-field=osdch]").val(localStorage.getItem("osdch"));
$("input[data-field=kiz]").val(localStorage.getItem("kiz"));

$("body").on("click", "#buildTree", function (e) {
  ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое